# Coredll not found error in Windows 10 mobile enterprise application

Tags: c#, uwp, dllimport

We are developing a mobile application which works in Windows 10 mobile enterprise. Now there is a requirement to change the system time to a specific value. We tried the below

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME st);



[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct SYSTEMTIME
            {
                public short wYear;
                public short wMonth;
                public short wDayOfWeek;
                public short wDay;
                public short wHour;
                public short wMinute;
                public short wSecond;
                public short wMilliseconds;
            }
      SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
            st.wYear = 2018; // must be short
            st.wMonth = 6;
            st.wDay = 21;
            st.wHour = 0;
            st.wMinute = 0;
            st.wSecond = 0;
 SetSystemTime(ref st);
```

But it throws coredll is not found. We are using uwp and C# as language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not set the system time in UWP app, And [`DateTimeSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.datetimesettings) API only available in IoT device. I found you want to import `coredll.dll` static method. Unfortunately, it is not available in UWP . For setting system time within UWP app, there are many roundabout way. For example, you could launch system date [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) page then setting time.

```
var uriDateSetting = new Uri(@"ms-settings:dateandtime");

// Set the option to show a warning
var promptOptions = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
promptOptions.TreatAsUntrusted = true;

// Launch the URI
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriDateSetting, promptOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DllImport` in UWP app to call Win32 API is kind of hack.

I have found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465357/815938) and [this blog post](https://mtaulty.com/2016/01/11/windows-10-uwp-and-pinvoke-getnativesysteminfo/).

Firstly, is that you can only call a set of selected API. `SetSystemTime` is not in the [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592902.aspx#Time). Setting system time is a restricted permission, my guess is that the system doesn't grant such a permission to the app.

Secondly, according to the linked answer, the signature of the `DllImport API` is importing from something like `api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll`, weird, right?

Comment: but windows CE supports this coredll.

Comment: I don't know, but it has been 5 years since Win CE's latest release, it is not Windows 10 Mobile. You best bet is trying to import it from "api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll", as it is where `GetSystemTime` resides.

Comment: Thanks, @kennyzx .But this dll is not working for SetSystemTime.